# force format an encrypted/read only memory card

Tags: 12.04, command-line, usb-drive

I had 1 GB memory card which I was using with my blackberry mobile. I suppose it was encrypted and read only. When is insert the memory card it shows the following file in it `9æ£¥z.C6` pretty weird name it is.
I can't format the card as it shows read only files! Is my card permanently doomed? anyway by which i can recover it?

Attached is the image depicting card contents>> [cardContents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gobc.png)

I have already tried using windows 8 disk utility, ubuntu disk utility as well as terminal, none of them worked for me. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried all sort of things using ubuntu disk utility and `gksu nautilus`, and then inserted the memory card in my windows PC. Viola, it worked. windows asked me to format the disk utility before using, hence done

Answer (score 0):

You probably already tried this, but check the file's permissions. Odds are that you can't edit them to enable write, so you probably need to change them as root. If you don't know how to `chmod`, you can `sudo nautilus` and try to enable writing from there.

Comment: i have tried `sudo chmod 777 *` after navigating to that directory, but it doesn't work for me, a part of the output is shown here>> http://paste.ubuntu.com/6627190/

Comment: Also tried `sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb1` which didn't work